# What tools should I use for DNS diagnostic?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain-name, dns-hosting

I am trying to host a domain name (pressemag.com) on my dedicated server.

1. I have put DNS the domain name provider gave me
2. I put the .pressemag.com A 88.190.22.44
3. but nothing.. site is totally inaccessible

I have no idea where what of these 3 steps is wrong:

**Are there some diagnosis tools so I can know what step is wrong:** 
The DNS provided by register? My DNS A parameter or my apache config?

Comment: I don't use a leading `.` when adding aliases, usually a trailing dot. Also, are you trying to host your own dns? if so, you will have to point to your nameservers in there system, they should have instructions to do so. I can't resolve your site either so it's not a local issue, fwiw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `dig` utility from dns-utils (packaged with bind usually), and use the `+trace` option.

[Output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=c2NDaWLe)

Your dns servers seem to be "dns200.anycast.me"  and "ns200.anycast.me". Is this correct? They returned no response, so start looking there. If you've changed DNS server addresses, the change can take some time to propagate (in my experience, up to 24hours).

Answer (score 5):

Kudos for not obfuscating your domain name! In addition to the reply from @Mulaz, you can use the [public dnscheck service](http://dnscheck.iis.se/?time=undefined&id=undefined&test=standard&view=basic&setLanguage=en) from the Swedish registry. It shows the same as mulaz says - your domain is supposed to be handled by anycast.me, but their servers don't have any information about it. So you need to contact your DNS provider and ask what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

`nslookup` is a basic but useful tool. `ping` and `traceroute` will tell you if the name resolved, but nslookup will give you the name associated with an IP, vice versa, and also the server that returned that answer. A sample output is below:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>nslookup google.com
Server:  safewall.dyndns.org
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:806::100e
          74.125.225.65
          74.125.225.68
          74.125.225.67
          74.125.225.66
          74.125.225.73
          74.125.225.78
          74.125.225.72
          74.125.225.71
          74.125.225.70
          74.125.225.69
          74.125.225.64


C:\Users\me\Desktop>nslookup 74.125.225.73
Server:  safewall.dyndns.org
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    ord08s07-in-f9.1e100.net
Address:  74.125.225.73
```